# Use Tails Persistent volume with ISO

Tags: tails, persistent

I have a USB stick contaning a number of ISO images that uses Grub to boot into whichever one is selcted from its menu. One of these ISOs is Tails.

Part of the USB stick is partitioned as a persistent volume that Tails recognises when booted from the ISO. I have not used it much but first impressions are that it works fine.

I also tried a persistent volume on a separate USB stick and that also worked fine.

Now I am aware that the Tails website suggests that

> It is only possible to create a persistent volume if the device, USB stick or SD card, was installed using Tails Installer.

However, my experience shows that it works fine with an ISO. Sure, Tails won't *create* a persistent volume when booted from an ISO, but it will use one that it finds on a conected storage device.

So I want to ask whether there are any reasons to recommend against using an ISO image and persistent volume in this way.

(Tails version 2.6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is fine to use an ISO image and persistent volume in the way the question describes. However, **You can create persistent volumes on any device but Tails won't do it for you and such configurations aren't supported.**

Tails persistent volumes can go on any device. From the [persistence design documentation](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/persistence):

> the underlying tools will support storage on whatever relevant device

and

> brave and advanced users can prepare their store their persistent data wherever they want

and

> this is not something we will actively support and document beyond the bare minimum (--help and manpage)

### How to create a persistent volume

1. Create a partition named `TailsData` (this is how Tails recognises a persistent partition);
2. Create a LUKS volume on the partition: `cryptsetup luksFormat ...`;
3. Create a EXT4 filesystem in the LUKS volume `mkfs.ext4 ...`;
4. Mount the filesystem (e.g. on `/mnt`);
5. Set ACLS on the root directory: `setfacl -m user:115:rwx,group::rwx,mask::rwx /mnt`;
6. Create file `/mnt/persistence.conf` with mode `600` and ownership `155:122`, with contents as descrbed below.

Tails uses the `persistence.conf` file to mount diretories on the persistent volume onto the filesystem. For example, the line

```
/home/amnesia/Persistent source=Persistent
```

makes the `Persistent` directory on the persistent volume available as the `/home/amnesia/Persistent` directory. When Tails creates this file. the whitespace between the two parts is a `tab`, however a `space` also works.

A more complete example `persistence.conf` is shown below:

```
/home/amnesia/Persistent source=Persistent
/home/amnesia/.gnupg source=gnupg
/home/amnesia/.ssh source=openssh-client
/home/amnesia/.purple source=pidgin
/home/amnesia/.claws-mail source=claws-mail
/home/amnesia/.gnome2/keyrings source=gnome-keyrings
/home/amnesia/.mozilla/firefox/bookmarks source=bookmarks
/etc/cups source=cups-configuration
/home/amnesia/.icedove source=icedove
```

### An example

Given the GPT partition `/dev/sdj3`, as `root` :

```
# cryptsetup luksFormat /dev/sdj3
# cryptsetup open /dev/sdj3 tailsdata
# mkfs.ext4 /dev/mapper/tailsdata
# mount /dev/mapper/tailsdata /mnt
# echo '/home/amnesia/Persistent source=Persistent' > /mnt/persistence.conf
# chown 115:122 /mnt/persistence.conf
# chmod 600 /mnt/persistence.conf
# setfacl -m user:115:rwx,group::rwx,mask::rwx /mnt
# umount /mnt
# cryptsetup close tailsdata
```

**It is important to set the permissions (`chown`, `chmod` and `setfacl`) correctly otherwise Tails will disable persistence.**

Tails will create the directories defined in `persistence.conf`. If you want to precreate them set their ownership appropriately (`1000:1000` for content beneath `/home/amnesia`; as appropriate for other directories).

Tails will also create an empty file called `live-additional-software.conf`. This is an optional file that allows additional packages to be installed from the persistent volume. See [here](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/persistence/configure/#index14h2) for more information about this.

When mounted, the root of the persistent volume is at `/live/persistence/TailsData_unlocked`.

### Further reading:

- [Persistence Design Documetation](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/persistence)
- [Create & configure the persistent volume](https://tails.boum.org/doc/first_steps/persistence/configure)

Answer (score 0):

Same thing - at the end, whoever created *a kernel-recognizable persistent volume* - it's *just mounted and used*. No difference at all in any matters.